# Deriving the Gauss-Bonnet term from the Euler class

Tags: general-relativity, differential-geometry, curvature, topology

The Gauss-Bonnet term is just the Euler class of $4D$ manifolds. The Euler class is defined as $$e(\Omega) = \text{Pf}(\Omega)$$ where $\Omega$ is the curvature two-form and $\text{Pf}(\Omega)$ is its Pffafian. What I don't understand is how does the Pffafian generate a term like $R_{\mu\nu\rho\sigma}R^{\mu\nu\rho\sigma}$, all I got was $R_{\mu\nu}R^{\mu\nu}$ and $R^2$ ? Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Pfaffian of a $4$-by$4$ matrix $\Omega$ is
$$
{\rm Pf}(\Omega)= \frac 1{2.2^2} \epsilon^{abcd} \Omega_{ab}\Omega_{cd}
$$
The curvature two-form is
$$
\Omega_{ab}= \frac 1{2} R_{ab\mu\nu} dx^\mu\wedge dx^\nu 
$$
so
$$
{\rm Pf}(\Omega)= \frac 1{32} \epsilon^{abcd}  R_{ab\mu\nu}  R_{cd\rho\sigma} dx^\mu\wedge dx^\nu \wedge dx^\rho\wedge dx^\sigma\\
=  \frac 1{32} \epsilon^{abcd}  R_{ab\mu\nu}  R_{cd\rho\sigma}\epsilon^{\mu\nu\rho\sigma} d^4x.
$$
Now
$$
\epsilon^{abcd}\epsilon^{\mu\nu\rho\sigma}= \delta^a_\mu\delta^b_\nu\delta^c_\rho \delta^d_\sigma +(perms)
$$
The are $24$ perms in total.

Comment: I spent the entire day to work this out and figured it out. I used exactly the same method as you have.

Comment: I imagine it would take a day to work though the 24 terms! :)